# Producing in json format all data

Tags: java, json, jersey

Need your help! When i producing JSON format at specific URL. I got all the data in JSON format from mine application. For example instead of to produce  only the post information i got the getMessageByID and getAllMessage all in one time...

"The URL: http://localhost:8080/Messenger/rest/messenger/messeger/i%20love%20running/Maks/Burkov/32059087"

Why it producing the All information ? 
Here is what i get:

What do i need to do to produce only the @Post information ?

```
{
"name": "Maks",
"lastname": "Burkov",
"meessegaDate": 1461776715593,
"id_messenger": 32059087,

I need only the 4 lines above! 

"message": "i love running",
"allmessages": [
"i love running"
]
}

@Path("/messeger")
public class MessageResource {


@POST
@Path("/{message}/{messager_name}/{messager_last_name}/{messager_id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public MessengerDatabase ddMessage(@PathParam("message") String message, @PathParam("messager_name")String messager_name, @PathParam("messager_last_name")String messager_last_name ,@PathParam("messager_id") long messager_id){

MessengerDatabase mes = new MessageService().addMessage(message, messager_name, messager_last_name, messager_id);

return mes;

}

@GET
@Path("/{messager_id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String GetMessageById(@PathParam("messager_id") long id){

    String message = new MessageService().getMessageById(id);

    System.out.println(message);

    return message;
}

@GET
@Path("/allmess")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<String> getAllMessages(){
    return new MessageService().getAllMessages();
}
```

}

The Messenger Databse:

```
public class MessengerDatabase {

public MessengerDatabase() {}


public MessengerDatabase(String message, long id){

    setMessageByid(message, id);

}

public MessengerDatabase(String message, String messager_name, String messager_lastname,long messager_id) {

    Date date_generator = new Date();

    setMeessegaDate(date_generator);
    setId_messenger(messager_id);
    setMessage(message);
    setMessageByid(message,messager_id);
    setLastname(messager_lastname);
    setName(messager_name);
    System.out.println("In Constuctor");
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
private void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}
private void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
public Date getMeessegaDate() {
    return meessegaDate;
}
private void setMeessegaDate(Date meessegaDate) {
    this.meessegaDate = meessegaDate;
}
public long getId_messenger() {
    return id_messenger;
}
private void setId_messenger(long id_messenger) {
    this.id_messenger = id_messenger;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

private void setMessage(String message) {

    this.message = message;
}

private void setMessageByid(String message, long id){

    allmessages.add(message);
    message_by_messenger_id.put(id,message);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MessengerDatabase [name=" + name + ", lastname=" + lastname
            + ", meessegaDate=" + meessegaDate + ", id_messenger=" +   id_messenger + ", message=" + message + "]";
}

public List<String> getAllmessages() {
    return allmessages;
}

public String getMessage_by_messeger_id(long id) {

    String messageById = message_by_messenger_id.get(id);

    return messageById;
}


private static Map<Long,String> message_by_messenger_id = new HashMap<>();
private static List<String> allmessages = new ArrayList<>();

private String name;
private String lastname;
private Date meessegaDate;
private long id_messenger;
private String message;

web xml:

 <display-name>Messenger</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>MessengerTest</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
<param-value>messenger.resources</param-value>
</init-param>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>MessengerTest</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/messenger/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: How is MessengerDatabase defined? Could you specify the URL you are using?

Comment: Thanks for comment.. I added MessengerDatabase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does your post have that path?

`@Path("/{message}/{messager_name}/{messager_last_name}/{messager_id}")`

I would do this:

```
    @Path("/message")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public MessengerDatabase ddMessage(Message message){

MessengerDatabase mes = new MessageService().addMessage(message);

return mes;
```

I think your paths are conflicting each other... posting variables in path params is not the best design...

here's a link that will help you in redesigning your API if you wish : 
http://blog.octo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/OCTO-Refcard_API_Design_EN_3.0.pdf

Comment: Ok Thanks! Path Params is for transferring data in path.. 
I don't think there is problem in conflict.. Because i get all information from Resource class, the problem is in URL specifying.. My application is produces the json format from all methods in resource class.. even if i set the path to concrete method!

Answer (score 0):

Your POST method is returning MessengerDatabase.

```
@POST
@Path("/{message}/{messager_name}/{messager_last_name}/{messager_id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public MessengerDatabase ddMessage(@PathParam("message") String message, @PathParam("messager_name")String messager_name, @PathParam("messager_last_name")String messager_last_name ,@PathParam("messager_id") long messager_id){    
    MessengerDatabase mes = new MessageService().addMessage(message, messager_name, messager_last_name, messager_id);    
    return mes;    
}
```

This class will be converted to JSON using the configured JSON writer. That JSON writer will typically take all readable JavaBeans properties in MessengerDatabase object and serialize them to JSON. The MessengerDatabase class has all the properties you receive in the output defined per JavaBeans conventions - no-arg getters(). I have added corresponding getters below.

```
{
"name": "Maks", ==> getName()
"lastname": "Burkov", ==> getLastname() 
"meessegaDate": 1461776715593, ==> getMeessegaDate()
"id_messenger": 32059087, ==> getId_messenger() 

I need only the 4 lines above! 

"message": "i love running", ==> getMessage()
"allmessages": [ ==> getAllmessages()
"i love running"
]
}
```

The getMessage() and getAllmessages() causes them to be added to the output. If you do not want these in the output you could define a DTO (another MessengerDatabase like POJO) without these properties, map your MessengerDatabase instance to it and return that DTO.

> Note

You may want to revisit the way you are using static variables.